# Prevent k-button class from being used - Telerik KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-window

I have a kendo pop-up window which is automatically applying the `k-button` class to buttons within that window.

```html
<button data-role="button" title="Save record and close" class="btn btn-primary k-button" style="" id="saveClose" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">Save &amp; Close</button>
```

Here is the original button

```html
<div class="btn-group mr5">
  <button id="del" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" title="Delete>
 <i class=" fa fa-minus mr5 "></i>
  Delete
  </button>
</div>
```

What I want is when the grid is loaded, it does NOT add the `k-button` class to the button.

Comment: why not just add some jquery like $("button").removeClass('k-button') to remove the class.

Comment: I had done it like this but the requirement is that it is never generated in the first place.

Comment: Other than adding your own buttons onto the popup  there isn't much you can do about it. As they are part of the framework they will be styled by Kendo.  alternatively if you don't want their styling on the button's just override the css with your own.

Comment: I'm assuming your buttons are simple HTML buttons and not Kendo buttons, right?

Comment: The buttons are html buttons yes. I want the bootstrap styling to take priority over the kendo styling

Comment: Could you post the code for your original button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce this issue but I have tried to provide solution for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="OpenWin">OPEN</button>
        <div id="window">
            <button data-role="button" title="Save record and close" class="btn btn-primary"
                id="saveClose" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
                Save &amp; Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var window = $("#window");
            $("#OpenWin").click(function (e) {
                window.data("kendoWindow").open();
            });
            window.kendoWindow({
                width: "505px",
                height: "315px",
                title: "Rams's Ten Principles of Good Design",
                actions: ["Pin", "Refresh", "Maximize", "Close"],
                open: hideButtonStyle,
                activate: hideButtonStyle,
                refresh: hideButtonStyle,
                visible: false
            });
        });
        function hideButtonStyle(e) {
            //Below code line remove all CSS class from the button
            $("#saveClose").removeClass();
            //Below code line re-add your existing CSS class
            $("#saveClose").addClass("btn btn-primary");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer. A rep from Telerik said on their forums that the only way to do this is using the jQuery method.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-remove-class-k-button-and-add-classes-from-bootstrap-like-btn-btn-danger#glUzE4Uht0Wkwzv6JUmaLQ

Answer (score 0):

I have since done this through Css instead of JS using the following code

```
.btn.k-button{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
    font-weight: 400; 
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.btn.k-button:hover{
    background-color:#2e6da4;
}
```